# Bash скрипт - строчка, которая комментирует сама себя

Tags: bash

Возможно ли написать на bash команду, которая комментирует сама себя в файле?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как мне кажется, я нашёл идеальное решение моей задачи.
Тут самое главное переменная $LINENO, которая и показывает номер текущей строки в скрипте.
Теперь можно делать скрипт, который после успешного выполнения команды сам себя комментирует.

```
 ls && sed -i ''$LINENO' s/^/#/' $0
```

Comment: Ну или так. Не забудьте взять `$0` в кавычки, на случай если в имени скрипта есть пробелы.

Comment: @igaraev, круто!

(жаль, не можете поставить галку сам себе).

Comment: @avp, Свои ответы можно принимать по истечении трех дней с момента публикации вопроса.

Answer (score 5):

Ну например:

```
[vladd@Kenga] [19:49:21] [~]
{0,120}$> cat selfmod.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo start
T=$(mktemp -u) && sed '/DELETETHISLINE/s/^/#/' <$0 >$T && rm -f $0 && mv $T $0
echo finish

[vladd@Kenga] [19:49:24] [~]
{0,121}$> ./selfmod.sh
start
finish

[vladd@Kenga] [19:49:29] [~]
{0,122}$> cat selfmod.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo start
#T=$(mktemp -u) && sed '/DELETETHISLINE/s/^/#/' <$0 >$T && rm -f $0 && mv $T $0
echo finish
```

---

Если нужно не пересоздавать файл, можно так:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo start
sed -i '/DELETETHISLINE/s/^/#/' "$0"
echo finish
```

Оказывается, `sed` умеет редактировать файл in place, так что получилось даже проще.

Comment: У вас файл каждый раз заново пересоздаётся.
А можно не пересоздавая файл?

Comment: @igaraev: Можно, обновил ответ.

Comment: @igaraev: [sed -i также пересоздаёт файл: создаёт временный файл и переименовывает его в конце](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9834294). В общем случае, даже если в файл был добавлен всего один байт (например, знак комментария), это приводит к переписыванию всего содержимого до конца (все последующие байты вынуждены сдвинуться на одну позицию в файле).